# jquery.ajax post request to get data from app engine server

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, google-app-engine

Apologies up front for the noob question...

Hello, how do I get data from the Python end of an appengine server using jQuery.ajax? I know how to send data to the server using ajax and an appropriate handler, but I was wondering if someone could tell me what the ajax request for getting values from the server looks like. (Suppose I wanted to get a number from the datastore and use it in the javascript).

client sending to server (using jquery)

client-side javascript:

```
//jQuery and ajax function loaded.

<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = {"salary":500};
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/resultshandler",
    data: data
</script>
```

server-side:

```
class ResultsHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        n = cgi.escape(self.request.get('salary'))
        e = Engineer(salary = n)
        e.put()
```

and under def main():, I have the handler ('/put_in_datastore', ResultsHandler)

Again, what would be the similar code for retrieving numbers from the Python end? If someone could provide both the handler code and javascript code that would be great...

Comment: Why on earth are you escaping values using `cgi` before storing them in the datastore?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The mechanism is exactly the same either way the data is flowing. Use the `success` parameter on the ajax call to operate on the data after the request successfully finishes. This is generally called a **callback**. Other callbacks exist. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for the complete information.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/resultshandler",
  type: 'POST',
  data: data,
  success: function(data, status){
    //check status
    //do something with data
  }
});
```

On the Python end, you return data with `self.response.write.out(output)`. See example below.

```
class ResultsHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        k = db.Key.from_path('Engineer', the_engineer_id) #will be an integer
        e = db.get(k)
        output = {'salary': e.salary}
        output = json.dumps(output) #json encoding
        self.response.write.out(output)
```

Also, your url routing should look like `('/resultshandler', ResultsHandler)`. I don't know where `/put_in_datastore` came from.

Finally, notice the `def post` rather than `def get` because I'm making a `POST` request with the Javascript. You could do the same as a `GET` request, and in that case you'd use `def get`.

Comment: Hmm... I keep on getting POST http://localhost:8110/resultshandler 500 (Internal Server Error). I tried doing output = {'salary':500} but no luck and alert(data) under the success function but no luck...

Comment: Don't forget the json encoding. Pastebin your code and I might be able to help.

Comment: and what error are you getting on the server? Check the logs for the python stacktrace.

Comment: ah, turns out that I assumed the python 2.6 runtime to support json.dumps. I fixed it by using simplejson.dumps function. Thanks for the dedicated 1-on-1 support :D

Comment: update, I'm getting a 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read 'salary' property of null'. The web worker works fine in chrome but raises this error, whereas it does not work in Firefox at all. any advice?