# How to call to a python handler from jquery ajax?

Tags: python, html, jquery, tipfy

How to call to a python handler from jquery ajax? can any one give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/resultshandler",
  type: 'POST',
  data: data,
  success: function(data, status){
    //check status
    //do something with data
  }
});
```

may this post will help you [jquery.ajax post request to get data from app engine server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184450/jquery-ajax-post-request-to-get-data-from-app-engine-server/7185256#7185256)